# How to use setTimer and teswaitXXXX function in test module with CAPL

Tags: capl

I'm trying to make automated test cases with CAPL in test module.

First problem I faced is that I can't use setTimer in CAPL.

As I know, setTimer is activated in [on Start] but It can't be used in test moduel.

When I try to call setTimer in testcase, It was not called at all.

my code like this, I want to make timer cyclic every 6 sec.

```
on timer Timer_1{
  setTimer(Timer_1,6000);
}
testcase TestCase_1()
{
    setTimer(Timer_1,6000);
}
void MainTest()
{
  TestCase_1();
}
```

What is the problem in this code and how to use setTiemr in test module ?

Second question is that how to use testwaitXXXX function in CAP.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fy1A.png)

For example, I want to use those kind of fuction to wait untill specific variable is changed.

But I can't get information about 1st parameter which is "valueHanlde * coValue".

Is that a kind of handler ?

How can I use it ? please give me example code to use it.

I want to use it for checking flag value.

For example,

```
int flag  = 0;

testWaitForeChangeFlag(flag,100000);
```

Thanks
BR

I've tried to run setTimer and testWaitForXXX fuctions in test module. But it was failed.

Comment: Ask one question at a time and please be clear.

Comment: Please spare some efforts in referring CAPL help for testwaitfortimeout,

Answer (score 0):

```
variables
{
  msTimer Timer_1;
}

 

void mainTest()
{
  Testcase_1();
}

 

testcase Testcase_1()
{
  write("TC called");
  setTimerCyclic(Timer_1,60); 

  testWaitForTimeout(6000);
}

 

on timer Timer_1
{
  write("Your data");
}
```

The problem might be that your test case is ending before the timer is even being called. Introduce a delay with testwaitfortimeout and re-run the above code